# Write to different Sheets in a single excel file from multiple tables

Tags: spring-batch

Can someone please give me a technical design overview of how I should implement this scenario :

I am using spring batch to import data from CSV files to different tables and once they are imported I run some validations on these tables and now I need to write all those data from 3 different tables into three different Sheets of a single Excel file. Can someone please help me how I should use ItemReaders and Itemwriters to solve this problem ?

Comment: For the love of the god I never asked to give me the code. Please be polite. I was asking for a technical design flow. Because I had to write seperate ItemReaders for seperate tables and seperate ItemWriters for each of these because each sheet has different column headers and values from these tables. I was looking for a much better way if someone could give me a hint in reading the data from multiple tables and writing it to a single excel in seperate sheets utilizing the spring batch out of the box features. So that's the problem I am facing.

Comment: @bellabax can you undo the negative reputation you have given me. By no means my question was a give me the code thing. This is highly unacceptable and unprofessional. If it was like that why would you see someone responding with a beautiful thought how to attack this scenario? Please see below FYI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm asked I would implement as follows. create xls file from your code or first step which would be method invoker. which would create the file. and pass the file job parameters.

1. Step 1/2 would do a chunk reading from table 1 and in the itemwriter I would use the custom Item writer which would use POI and I would write to first sheet.
2. Step 2 would do a chunk reading from table 2 and in the itemwriter would read second sheet.

Since you have single file you can never achieve the advantage of spring batch performance like multithread, partitioning etc. Rather than its better to write to different file with independent task

Comment: I finally did the same design. Like you pointed out its true I can't fully get the power of partitioning and reusing the same readers and writers. But that's what business wants rather than separate files. I have used SXSSF is an API-compatible streaming extension of XSSF of POI. It performs very nicely and no memory meltdown on the server as it has a sliding window.Thanks for your inputs.