# Writing data from multiple sources using spring batch and apache poi

Tags: java, excel, spring, apache-poi, spring-batch

I currently have a working spring batch application that uses an ItemReader to read an SQL view from an Oracle database and writes that data into an Excel file. However, I would like to read data from more than one view and write to the same Excel file - how can I achieve that?

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:c24="http://schema.c24.biz/spring-core"
    xmlns:bat-c24="http://schema.c24.biz/spring-batch" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
        http://schema.c24.biz/spring-core http://schema.c24.biz/spring-core.xsd
        http://schema.c24.biz/spring-batch http://schema.c24.biz/spring-batch.xsd">


    <bean id="launchHelper" class="com.launcher.management.DummyPreJobHelper" />
    <bean id="rowMapper" class="com.exporter.DynamicComplexDataObjectRowMapper"/>

    <bean id="itemReader" class="com.exporter.ViewJdbcCursorItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="viewName" value="V_CARS" />
        <property name="fetchSize" value="5000" />
        <property name="rowMapper" ref="rowMapper" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="itemWriter" class="com.exporter.ExcelFileItemWriter" scope="step">
        <property name="resource" value="file:${working.directory}/#{jobParameters['output.file']}" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Batch job configuration -->
    <batch:job id="excel-report-job">
        <batch:step id="export">
            <batch:tasklet allow-start-if-complete="true">
                <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="5000">
                    <batch:listeners>
                        <batch:listener>
                            <bean class="com.utils.LoggingStepListener" />
                        </batch:listener>
                    </batch:listeners>
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this link [Write to different Sheets in a single excel file from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076810/write-to-different-sheets-in-a-single-excel-file-from-multiple-tables).

I also wanted to do this once and I suggest in your "itemWriter" @BeforeStep try below steps and code.

1. Load the exel file and initialise your existing excel workbook object
2. If the file does not exists create new excel workbook object
3. Use the above workbook object and write to specific tab where you want your data to be in.

```
    File xlsxFile = new File(outputFilename);
    if (xlsxFile.exists() && !xlsxFile.isDirectory()) {
        InputStream fileIn = null;
        try {
            fileIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(xlsxFile), 100);
            workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(new XSSFWorkbook(fileIn), 100);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fileIn != null) {
                try {
                    fileIn.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100);
    }
```